# Rstudio EC2 - loading certain packages fails

Tags: ubuntu, amazon-ec2, rstudio

I am running RStudio via AWS EC2 instance. In preparation of implementing a cron job for an R script, I have set up the following test script (named 'TestBatch.R' and stored in my EC2 ubuntu home directory):

```
setwd("/home/path")
filename <- "_test.txt"
filename <- paste(as.character(Sys.time()), filename, sep="")
data <- paste("Output for ", as.character(Sys.time()), sep="")
write(x=data,file=filename)
```

I execute the test script without any problems via...

```
sudo R CMD BATCH TestBatch.R
```

...and the output is stored in the desired location.

The problem arises when I augment the above R script to load certain packages, for example:

```
setwd("/home/path")
library(XML)
filename <- "_test.txt"
filename <- paste(as.character(Sys.time()), filename, sep="")
data <- paste("Output for ", as.character(Sys.time()), sep="")
write(x=data,file=filename)
```

In this case the code seems to fail, i.e. no output is stored. The problem only occurs for some packages while it works for others (e.g. 'plyr'). Note that I have installed all relevant packages via the Rstudio EC2 browser interface.

What could be the problem and how can I solve it? Please provide an answer for an ubuntu newbie

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Installing the package via the terminal CLI solves my problem:

`sudo apt-get install r-cran-xml`